# Can you have a string and a integer in one vector?

Tags: c++

I just have a general question. Can you have a string and an integer in one vector? I am planning to display card names and numbers. I want to display both and wanting the numbers to be added up at the end. Can I do this?

Comment: You can convert ```int``` to ```string``` then assign all to a string vector?

Comment: Convert the strings to int before adding them

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk other way around is better, cheaper to keep ints and since OP wants to sum them up at the end saves additional casts

Comment: @deW1 how you will convert "ABCD" to int ?

Comment: can a 2d vector work?

Comment: Not unless the elements of the vector are some structure that contains both an `int` and a `string`.   However, you've made this an XY problem.   It would be easier to work with a string only,  and convert between the string and integral values (or the reverse) as needed

Comment: @deW1 And even if you did (by say encoding them), how would you sum them at the end?

Comment: You want each card has a number assigned?

Comment: @randomprogrammer Why not `map` <string card_name, int value>  ?

Comment: Probably best just to use a container struct with `int` and `string` members

Comment: @Landstalker an ace is worth a certain amount of points, is it not?

Comment: thanks guys I'll have a play around with it

Comment: This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should tell us what you're _actually_ trying to achieve. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: @deW1 perhaps ^^

Comment: @Landstalker how else would you sum it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The object is simple, all i want to achieve is printing out a bunch of cards and adding up the total amount that the cards are. For eg  a player has 5 cards, each card is worth 10 points. The output should be the name of each card and the total value which is 50 points.

Comment: @randomprogrammer the problem descriptions belongs into the question. [Edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `std::string` and `int` in one `std::vector`using [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

```
using ElementType = std::variant<std::string, int>;
std::vector<ElementType> v;
v.push_back(std::string("I am string"));
v.push_back(1);
```